# How to show a directed set always has a "largest element" using induction

Tags: order-theory

I know induction from my lower division classes, but have no idea what to do when it comes to sets. For example a directed set is such that every two elements has an upperbound. We are looking at power sets specifically with the inherited binary operation as inclusion. Where do I start from here?  I could say, well we can't have the empty set since it doesn't qualify(not sure to to reason this well). Does the definition imply I need at least 3 distinct elements? I believe we can assumed inclusion as in a, b are both contained in a bigger subspace c. Do I start off by saying, we have 3 elements such that a,b contained in c. Then c is maximal element. Next, we have 4 elements? Any help? I believe since I'm asked to use induction it implies the set is infinite.

Actually, I also would like clarification on what a maximal element truly means? I always thought it contains the lower sets within it.(My class is using inclusion for the set binary operation)

Comment: A directed set does not always have a maximal element. $(ℕ,<)$ is directed.

Comment: In my paper I believe it has a less than or equal to sign. Does that make any difference?

Comment: @use140218 No, any two elements of $(ℕ,≤)$ have an upper bound, but there is no maximal element. What is your paper? Maybe we have conflicting definitions of directed sets. I’m using the [wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_set).

Comment: In my paper we are looking at power sets and my teacher drew a two dots connected to one dot to represent that the two dots were contained in the other dot. In power sets aren't they ordered by inclusion?

Comment: @user140128 Okay, so you are talking about special cases of directed sets: Directed systems of subsets.

Comment: Yes, I think so, I should have stated that but I'm new to the set language

Comment: You should edit your question and explain the exact statement you want to prove. Do you consider only systems of subsets of a *finite* set? Before that, one can only guess what your task is.

Comment: k.stm, does the directed set definition in general require at least 3 elements in it? Or am I wrong to interpret it that way? Since the definition has for every a,b there exists a bigger c.

Comment: It does not. It might already convince you to say “The elements $a, b, c$ can all be the same.” But this is only half the truth: Generally, requiring that something holds *for all* elements (or pairs/triples of elements) doesn’t mean that *there are* such elements (let alone that there are such pairs/triples of *different* elements).

Comment: Here's my guess about what the question is: Since the proof is supposed to be by induction, the result to be proved is probably that every *finite* directed set has a largest element. This formulation also has the advantage of being true, provided "directed" is defined correctly so as to exclude the empty set. Furthermore, the "largest" in the title is more likely to be correct than the "maximal" in the question; both versions are true but the former is stronger yet easier to prove by induction. Finally, I conjecture that the restriction to power sets is not intended.

Comment: So if a,b,c are equal then we have a,b, is contained in c? so I can have one element? Basically I do not know how small my set can be to quialify